# How to concatenate variables comes from model in controller

Tags: codeigniter, concatenation

I need to concatenate variables come from model.I send the role_id from controller to model and get the role name according to its id.
controller:

```
function get_role_name(){
$data['rec']=$this->amodel->get_section();
foreach($data['rec'] as $i)
{
$name['x']=$this->amodel->get_name($i->role_id);
}
$this->load->view('sections',array_merge($data,$name));
}
```

I write `$name['x'].=$this->amodel->get_name($i->role_id);` but it shows the error which `undefined index:x`.How can I concatenate the role name in cotroller to send it to view?

Answer (score 0):

you probably didnt define $name

```
$name = array();
// your foreach 
foreach ()
```

btw, the concatenating was ok
    $var = "foo";
    $var .= "foo"
    // will result in "foofoo"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append something using the .= syntax you need to make sure the variable or array exists first.

Try this:

```
function get_role_name(){
    $data['rec']=$this->amodel->get_section();
    $name = array();
    foreach($data['rec'] as $i) {
       if (isset($name['x'])) {
          $name['x'] .= $this->amodel->get_name($i->role_id);
       } else {
          $name['x'] = $this->amodel->get_name($i->role_id);
       }          
    }
    $this->load->view('sections',array_merge($data,$name));
}
```